# How to set bin path of sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have installed 3 MSSQL Server versions, `2005`,`2008R2` and `2012`. I want to set bin path of SQL Server `2008R2` version.
How to find bin path of SQL Server 2008 R2 version?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to set bin path of SQL Server 2008 R2 version. How to find bin path of SQL Server 2008 R2 version?

You don't set Bin path for SQL Server. The BINN directly is set by SQL Server at location(assuming C as System drive)

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLXX.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn
```

No mater where you install SQL Server the BINN directory would always go to C drive assuming C is your OS drive.

BINN is directory where binary files related to SQL Server are dumped that is internal to SQL Server application and you should NOT change it or try to change it you would mess up the installation.

The default installation directories has been documented by Microsoft BOL team In [this Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143547%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

This is what I understood from your question, if you want to clarify further edit your question and add more details